# JSON issue to store a function and remove the quotes

Tags: json, angularjs, node.js, kendo-grid

I try to create a json from my server and retrieve the JSON in the client angular. But my json is a function.

I create this JSON in the server:

```
var header = {};

var editor = 'function (container, options) {jsdd.appendTo(container);  $compile(editor)($scope); editor.css("visibility", "visible")};';

header['editor'] = editor;
```

In the client I retrieve my json like this:

```
editor: "function (container, options) {jsdd.appendTo(container); $compile(editor)($scope); editor.css("visibility", "visible")};"
```

However it doesn't work because I would like to remove the quotes and get this:

```
editor: function (container, options) {jsdd.appendTo(container); $compile(editor)($scope); editor.css("visibility", "visible")};
```

How can I do it?

---

**Updates**

The result I try to obtain from the json sent by the server is this:

```
 {
     title: "category",
     field: "category",
     editor: function (container, options) {
     var editor = $('<input kendo-drop-down-list required k-data-text-field="\'valueen\'" k-data-value-field="\'id\'" k-data-source=\"mapDSource.get(\'category\')\" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
     .appendTo(container);

     $compile(editor)($scope);
     editor.css("visibility", "visible");
     }

     , template: "{{getName(dataItem, 'category', 'id', 'valueen')}}"
     ,   type: 'string',
     editable: true,
     width: 250
     },
     {
     title: 'keyen',

     type: 'string',
     field: 'keyen',
     editable: true,
     validation: {
     required: true

     }, ....
```

All works excepted the editor parameter that is a function so what I am doing is the following and it works:

```
 var table = {};

    table.type = "referential";

    gridService.loadTable(table).success(function (data) {

        if(data.header)
        {
            var i;
            for(i in data.header)
            {
                var editor = data.header[i]['editor'];
                if(editor)
                {
                    data.header[i]['editor'] = new Function("container", "options", editor);
                }
            }
        }
   ....
```

Comment: what is the use case that you need to pass functions as strings in json? looks like a design flaw

Comment: I am using sails.js and design my model on my server. I add some custom parameters such as dropdown ... Then I build my grid config in the server and sends it to my client. The json is loaded with Kendo ui grid and all works. However for the editor part, it does not because the editor is a function. And I would like to create the function to execute in the json also. See here: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Althgough `eval` is NOT a good idea, it may be the only option (assuming you don't change your current implementation, which i feel you should).

```js
h['editor'] = eval('('+editor+')');
```

I feel bad for recommending `eval`.

---

As a side note, one quick way to avoid `eval` is return only the body of the function in the json string (the part between the curly brackets):

```
var editor = 'jsdd.appendTo(container);  $compile(editor)($scope); editor.css("visibility", "visible");'
```

Then define `header['editor']` like this:

```
header['editor'] = new Function("container","options",editor);
```

Comment: The issue with your solution is that editor is a part of an array of columns. Each column can have an editor. So I will need to loop over every column and add eval for each editor property? How can I do it? May I not just remove quotes of the json retrieved? For example for numbers or boolean property I have no quotes. I would like the same for the editor function.

Comment: You see from kendo ui grid: 

columns.editor: Function

Provides a way to specify a custom editing UI for the column. Use the container parameter to create the editing UI.

Link: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.editor

Comment: No, removing the quotes won't do it. You need to somehow compile that string into an expression. One better option than `eval` is to only return the function body as the json string and create a new function for the editor variable (see my updated answer). Regarding your second question, I am not sure how you retrieve your json values, but I assume you would loop through the columns array you pass to kendoGrid and define an editor for each item. traversing an array should be a trivial matter. Put a more complete code sample in your question to help you further..

Answer (score 0):

I think [$parse](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse) is what you're looking for. I may be missing some context, but this seems like a weird use case. Why don't you just get a .js file in the http request instead of this stringified JS in a JSON object business?

Comment: I use Kendo UI grid. I have my grid model in the server. I setup some properties and send a json to my client which contains the whole grid config. The grid config is built on the fly in the server. If I need an editor dropdown, the only way to setupit with kendoui is to define it with a function. The issue is that with quotes, the function is interpreted as a string.